# Order of growth of real $x_{n}$ such that $\zeta(x_{n}) = 1 + \frac{1}{2^{n}}$

Tags: riemann-zeta

On a lark, I decided to calculate (via Newton's method and using [mpmath](http://code.google.com/p/mpmath/)) the real $x_{n}$ such that $\zeta(x_{n}) = 1 + \frac{1}{2^{n}}$ for as many $n\in\mathbb{N}$ as I could. What sort of surprised me is that as $n$ grew, $x_{n}$ started getting very close to $n$.

For $n=30$, $x_{30}\approx 30.0000075250944636973647\ldots$. 
For $n=100$, $x_{100}\approx 100.00000000000000000354853124\ldots$

<s>Is it true that $\zeta(2m)=(-1)^{m+1}\frac{B_{2m}(2\pi)^{2m}}{2(2m)!}$ grows as $1+\frac{1}{2^{2m}}$?</s>

(here is a [link](http://owen.maresh.info/zetlist) to a file containing $x_{n}$ for small $n$ to many digits of accuracy)

EDIT: as @sos440 pointed out, the series definition of the zeta function (that is valid on the real $s>1$) is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{s}}$, and taking the first two terms one obtains: $1 + \frac{1}{2^{n}} + \sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{s}}$.

Comment: Just carefully look at the defining series of the Riemann zeat function. Then you will soon find a reasonable explanation to this phenomenon.

Comment: @sos440: oh, I should have seen that.